# How to check if spatial search is working in Solr

Tags: php, google-maps, solr, spatial-query

I'm trying out the spatial search in Solr.
What I did was to stop the service, then updated the `schema.xml` file for `collection1`  to include the following:

```
<fieldType name="location" class="solr.LatLonType" subFieldSuffix="_coordinate"/>
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="tdouble" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>

<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location_0_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location_1_coordinate" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

And then I started the service again to update the document in Solr:

```
$local_select = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=ss_type:(business%20OR%20user%20OR%20blog)&wt=json';

$url = $local_select;
$data = file_get_contents($url);
$r_data = json_decode($data, true);

$docs = $r_data['response']['docs'];



if(!empty($docs)){
    foreach($docs as $doc){


        if(!empty($doc['tm_field_business_address:postal_code'][0])){

            $postal_code = urlencode($doc['tm_field_business_address:postal_code'][0]);

            $api = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' .  $postal_code . '&sensor=false';
            $api_results = file_get_contents($api);
            $data = json_decode($api_results, true);

            if($data['status'] == 'OK'){
                $location = $data['results'][0]['geometry']['location'];

                unset($doc['_version_']);

                $doc['location_0_coordinate'] = $location['lat'];
                $doc['location_1_coordinate'] = $location['lng'];
                $new_docs[] =  $doc;
            }
        }
    }
}




$local_update = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/update/json';
$local_commit = 'http://localhost:8080/solr/update?commit=true';

//update the solr index
if(!empty($new_docs)){
    $json_doc = json_encode($new_docs);

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-type:application/json"),
        CURLOPT_URL => $local_update,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $json_doc,
    ));

    $update_response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);


    //commit the changes
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $local_commit
    ));


    $commit_response = curl_exec($curl);
}
```

The curl responses were both ok and when I checked the results using this query:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=ss_type:(business%20OR%20user%20OR%20blog)
```

It returned the results:

```
<double name="location_0_coordinate">49.9641523</double>
<double name="location_1_coordinate">10.1378365</double>
```

Now my problem is have I really set this up properly? And if yes, what will be the query that I can use to check if its really returning something once I use a spatial query like the one below:

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?q=ss_type:(business%20OR%20user%20OR%20blog)&fq={!geofilt}&sfield=location&pt=49.9641523,10.1378365&d=0
```

My main problem here is that I don't really know what to supply for the reference point in order for it to return a record which already exists in the Solr index.

So for example if I have the following coordinates in the index:

```
49.9641523,10.1378365
```

What will be the spatial query that would return the specific record which has that coordinate.
I tried to use `d=0` but nothing is returned:

```
<response>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the latitude and longitude in the same field, separated by comma. E.g. `<latitude>,<longitude>`

Field type should be `location`.

```
<dynamicField name="*_coordinate"  type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Pass in the following parameters in your query:

`pt` - The Point to use as the center of the filter. Specified as a comma separated list of doubles. It is lat,lon.

`d` - The distance (in KM) from the point to the outer edge of whatever is being used to filter on

`sfield` - The field with coordinate.

The following sample gespatial query will return all locations within 5km of the specified point 49.9641523, 10.1378365

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=*:*&fq={!geofilt}&pt=49.9641523,10.1378365&sfield=location_coordinate&d=5
```

Comment: so something like: `$doc['location_coordinate'] = $location['lat'] . ',' . $location['lng']` ?

Comment: I'm getting an error if I do the one above: `Error adding field 'location_coordinate'='51.3223777,-0.1358427' msg=For input string: \"51.3223777,-0.1358427\"","code":400}}`

Comment: The field type has to be `location`

Comment: I just want to point out that there is a SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType (assigned to name "location_rpt" in the default schema).  It's much faster than LatLonType, particularly if you have a ton of data. But I still recommend LatLonType for spatial sorting/relevancy with geodist() if you need that.  Both can be used.

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out, there's actually a default dynamic field in the `schema.xml` file that allows you to store coordinates, it has a field type of `location`. so even if I have no access to the `schema.xml` file I can still define it like this:

```
$doc['locm_store'] = $location['lat'] . ',' . $location['lng'];
```

The equivalent in an xml document would be:

```
<field name="locm_store">123,456</store>
```

Where `123` is the latitude and `456` is the longitude.